# Unable to delete document in Azure Cosmos DB with Document Link - Java Async V2

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to delete a document in one of my Azure Cosmos DB Collection using the Java CosmosDB Async v2 Library with the document link. Every time I'm trying to perform the delete operation on the document I'm running into `Resource not found` issue. I'm not sure what I missed.

Here is what I have so far:

```java
public Document deleteDocument(String docId, String collectionName){
    RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
    PartitionKey key = new PartitionKey(docId);
    options.setPartitionKey(key);
    String documentLink = String.format("/dbs/%s/colls/%s/docs/%s", this.databaseName, collectionName, docId);
    LOGGER.info("DOCUMENT LINK:" + documentLink);
    return this.client.deleteDocument(documentLink, options).next().block().getResource();
  }
```

Here is the Document information from the Azure CosmosDB:
[image: Document Information]

Input:

```java
this.deleteDocument("beff44de-914a-4250-80c3-108b71989720", "SravanCollection");
```

Thank you

Comment: are you passing the right values?

Comment: https://github.com/erician/YCSB-with-delete/blob/827552397b0045e4b812815bc6e4572731aa0fbf/azurecosmos/src/main/java/com/yahoo/ycsb/db/AzureCosmosClient.java

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes. These are my values: databaseName: TodoDB, collectionName: SravanCollection, Document ID: provided the Document ID not the _rid. I also tried to delete using `_self` but it throws the same issue

Comment: Are you passing the right Partition Key?

Comment: Is your Partition Key  `/id`?

Comment: I'm relatively new to Cosmos DB. I'm not sure which one is my partition key but I'm passing the Document ID to delete the document

Comment: @SteveZhao yes. I updated the post with more details. Please let me know if you more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this in V4:

```
public Mono<CosmosAsyncItemResponse> deleteBookByID(String id, String partitionKey) {
    return container.deleteItem(id, new PartitionKey(partitionKey));}
```

You can find a full sample application here:
https://github.com/RaviTella/SpringBootWebFluxCosmosSQL/tree/master/ReadingListWebApp

This should work in V2. Make sure you pass the correct value for Partition key and id :

```
 private void deleteBookObservable(String id, String partitionKey) {
    String documentLink = String.format("/dbs/%s/colls/%s/docs/%s", databaseName, 
     collectionName, id);
    RequestOptions reqOpts = new RequestOptions();
    reqOpts.setPartitionKey(new PartitionKey(partitionKey));
    Observable<ResourceResponse<Document>> deleteObservable =
        getClient().deleteDocument(documentLink, reqOpts).toBlocking().first();  
  }
```

Its highly recommended to use the V4 for all new development. There are breaking changes from v2 to v4. V4 using Reactor core implementation of the reactive extensions.

Comment: Your example helps but I'm unable to get containers from the client. I'm using Java CosmosDB Async v2

Comment: Thank you very much.